# Cheating with hard links and NFS

Tags: nfs, hardlink

At what layer does the magic occur that allows me to hardlink files between two NFS mounts on the client when they’re on the same file system on the server? Also, can I trust these to act like normal hardlinks? Yes, this is a real thing that I see happening on the screen right in front of me.

Comment: yes, I think that you have two shares that reside on the same filesystem on server side.